# Звуковые сигналы системника

Tags: bios, cpu

Всем привет, у меня сгорел блок питания на пк. Я его сменил все установил и тд
Но при запуске он издает звуковые сигналы, проверял по очереди убирал комплектующие с системника, но все равно пищит. Залью файл со звуком на яндекс https://disk.yandex.ru/d/pU4tHRGo54c5rA
Материнка gigabyte b450m

Comment: Ошибка видеокарты

Comment: так если она не стоит как ошибка видеокарты?

Comment: 1 длинный, 3 коротких — видеоадаптер не обнаружен или имеет неполадки

Comment: Я понимаю сам чекал эту таблицу, но почему если я на втором пк вытаскиваю видюху у меня же не пищит пк?

Comment: Читал что еще проблемы с cpu может быть его я не вытаскивал завтра есть вариант поставить другой и проверить.

Comment: встроенного видео ядра тоже нету процессор ryzen 5 2600x

Comment: Может ли быть что слот pci сгорел?

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь в любом случае.

Comment: 1. Внешнее питание у видеокарты есть? Оно подключается? 2. Кулер видеокарты стартует при старте компьютера?